# How to prevent MediaPlayer from getting started when setPlaybackParams() is called using Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

In my project I need to ***set the playback params*** before the **MediaPlayer** is started (**MediaPlayer** will start when user clicks a *Button*). But when I set playback params using the code given below, the **MediaPlayer** automatically gets started.

```java
mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.5f));
```

Now, how would I prevent it from getting started?

(You can say, I might just set the params when button is clicked, but it won't work as I have several **MediaPlayer**s to set params.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `MediaPlayer`s doc:

> public void setPlaybackParams (PlaybackParams params)
>
> Sets playback rate using PlaybackParams. The object sets its internal PlaybackParams
> to the input, except that the object remembers previous speed when
> input speed is zero. This allows the object to resume at previous
> speed when start() is called. **Calling it before the object is prepared
> does not change the object state**. After the object is prepared,
> calling it with zero speed is equivalent to calling pause(). **After the
> object is prepared, calling it with non-zero speed is equivalent to
> calling start()**.

I suspect you call `mediaPlayer.prepare()` before you set the params or you have used `mediaPlayer.create()` (which is equivalent to call `mediaPlayer.setDataSource()` and `mediaPlayer.prepare()` both at the same time. So, you indirectly called `mediaPlayer.prepare()`), in which case the player will start playing when the params are set, exactly as described in the documentations.

So, use `mediaPlayer.setDataSource()` and then set playback params (so that it doesn't automatically start the `mediaPlayer`). After that call `mediaPlayer.prepare()` before calling `mediaPlayer.start()`.

Comment: You got it. I didn't call **mp.prepare()**, but I called **mp.create()** which is equivalent to call **mp.setDataSource()** and **mp.prepare()** at the same time. So, I indirectly called **mp.prepare()**. If you update your answer describing this issue (**mp.create()** issue), I will accept you answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change speed while not restarting, you could check playing status before then use this info to stop playing just after changing speed:
mediaPlayer is your Mediaplayer instance, speed is your value for speed

```
var isCurrentlyPlaying:Boolean=mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying
mediaPlayer!!.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer!!.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed))
if (!isCurrentlyPlaying) {
    mediaPlayer!!.pause()
}
```